software/app to resize images to set size
I have a gallery page featuring different users. Each user upload an image of themselves that is displayed on the gallery page.
My problem is that I need to fit all the images to a set size of 250PX by 200PX.
The images ultimately come out distorted like the image below:

Is there a software that I can use to resize all the images on the fly.
By the way, I use image intervention to make an initial resizing of images when users upload pictures.

I don't think this question belongs here - it is specific to a single site, and is about programming, not being a webmaster.    Might I suggest the solution is to work out how you want to handle the issue - ie did you want to pad the image, crop the image or how did you want to deal with the underlying issue?  (Its easy enough to resize images on the fly - the issue you have is HOW you want to resize them)

Object-fit in CSS is probably going to do what you're after.
img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

May sometimes crop a bit weirdly if the user's image is unusually framed, though.  And you should still reduce the size of images when uploaded, because people tend to upload huge images.
